# wpf DataGrid - Sort on Command only

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I have my own `DataGrid` component (inherited from `DataGrid`). I want this component to act like a MS Access grid. What I need is to sort the data once, when I invoke the method `MySort()` `(MyDataGrid.MySort)`

The `MySort` method uses `DataGrid` items collection, so I add `SortDescription` to `Items` and the `View Sorts`. The problem is that I don't want to re-sort this grid when an item is added or edited. Sorting might be invoked only by the `MySort` method.

How to prevent `DataGrid` from sorting when `Items.SortDescription` has some values? I need some property like `do_not_resort`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .Net framework 4 or above you can use the "CanUserSortColumns" property of the grid control to prevent automatic sorting.

And the MySort method of your custom grid can roughly look something like this.

```
public void MySort(DataGridSortingEventArgs args)
    {
        //create a collection view for the datasource binded with grid
        ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource);
        //clear the existing sort order
        dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();

        ListSortDirection sortDirection = args.Column.SortDirection ?? ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        //create a new sort order for the sorting that is done lastly
        dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(args.Column.SortMemberPath, sortDirection));

        //refresh the view which in turn refresh the grid
        dataView.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Kumar Veluswam
Thank You4 quick answer but I think that is not resolving my problem. That is what I did by myself.
I'm gonna use example to show You the key problem:
DataGrid displays values:
1
2
3
5
DataGrid is editable so I'm changing value 3 to 7 .....and then the DataGrid resorts (because SortDescriptions has columnname). I don't want it to resort automaticly when I add or modify item. Resorting can by done only by MySort method.

Comment: A CollectionViewSource sorts automatically. Have you tried binding a Generic List instead of CollectionViewSource, as it gives more control over sorting? Do you sort by multiple columns?